# Making multipe variables by data inputted

Tags: java, variables

Ok, Im pretty sure you can do this in PHP

but I am looping through a hashmap contain Strings and Strings, and I want to make each key string into an variable name of an object, Java doesnt recognise it, and I cant just make 1 object and change things after I loop through it.

I apoligise in advance if this is a really dumb question, but Im just confused.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't store variable name. Instead you actually store value referred by the object.

So if you have String say :

```
String key = "Hello";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key, key);
```

You are not storing key as string "key". Instead you are storing reference to String pointed by key which is "Hello" in this case.

Comment: Yes, but how do I in other method make objects based of all the keys in the hashmap and then do the exact same stuff to them all?

Comment: So if you have say "key1", "key2", "key3", just say `String value = map.get(key1);`

Comment: Nooooo I meant how do I make a varible name with those kets, like based off you previous answer'Dog value = new Dog();'

Comment: did you mean `Dog dog = new Dog(); map.put(dog, "Value").`?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question. Perhaps by name of variable you mean name of type of variable  (e.g. "String" , "Integer", "HashMap" etc)? If so, you don't use String for that in Java, you use a Class<?> object like String.class, Integer.class, Hashmap.class.